# Maintaining a set of small changes not to be committed to SCM

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial

I'm using git, but I'll be glad to hear answers relevant to other SCMs.

I'm having a few small changes which are relevant just for me (using a different build scheme, relevant only for my configuration), and I really need to have them.

The right thing to do is of course, merge it into the trunk, but *until* I'll merge it into the trunk I have to keep a list of changes which will not be committed.

So let's say I'm need to change my makefile to have `CC=mygcc` (since I need the gcc symlink pointing to a bad version for other software I'm compiling), but I don't want to commit it (others don't, so others don't want to have `mygcc` symlink).

What do I do to allow me easily synchronize and update the main repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mercurial, this is best done with an [mq patch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).

To make the initial patch:

```
cd <working copy>
hg qinit
...make changes to your working copy
hg qnew <patch_name>
```

Then, when it is time to pull changes from the remote or actually commit new local changes:

```
hg qpop -a        # remove all patches from your working copy
hg pull --update  # get new changesets from the remote and update to the latest
...work on local files
hg commit -m "commit changes without touching the patch"
hg push           # send changes to a remote repo that don't include the patch
hg qpush -a       # apply all patches to your updated working copy
```

Comment: Yes, this is super easy with mercurial patch queues!

Comment: Wait, please show how do you commit new revisions while the patch is on, and avoid committing the unwanted patch.

Comment: @Elazar: I updated my answer to show how you can commit changes without committing the 'unwanted' patch.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a comment on [Elazar Leibovich's second option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513945/maintaining-a-set-of-small-changes-not-to-be-commited-to-scm/5513982#5513982) which became a bit out-of-hand for a comment :)  In commit graph terms, I  would basically do the same as option 2, but maintain a local branch which has my changes rather than staying on master.  In other words, the usual state would be like this:

```
 A --- B --- C (master,origin/master) --- D --- E (local)
```

... if I want to update from master, I would do:

```
 git checkout local
 git fetch origin
 git rebase origin/master
```

... to get to:

```
A --- B --- C (master) --- F --- G (origin/master) --- D' --- E' (local)
```

If I'd added more commits onto `local`, I'd make that a `git rebase -i origin/master` so that I can make sure that my `D` and `E` are still most recent in the history.

The advantage of this over Elazar Leibovich's option 2 is just that it reduces the risk that you're going to accidentally push your local changes to `master` with `git push` or `git push master`, since your local changes will never be on the `master` branch and there should be no branch called `local` remotely.  (If there is, choose a different name, obviously :))

When you do have something you want to push back to `master`, for example the commits `H` and `I` here:

```
A -- B -- C (master) -- F -- G (origin/master) -- H -- I -- D'' -- E' (local)
```

... you would do:

```
git checkout master
git merge I
git push origin master
```

Comment: The tricky thing here is that you often want these changes no matter what branch you're on, so as you start developing more and more actively, you end up wanting to rebase a copy of this branch everywhere you go... it can start getting a bit unwieldy, and easy to miss something. It's still about the best you can do, though, far as I can tell. (Besides `update-index --assume-unchanged`, which always seemed a bit dodgy to me.)

Comment: I take your point, but I think that when I needed such changes in more than one branch I'd take it as a sign that it's worth introducing code into master such that the effects can be set via local configuration...

Comment: True enough, in general. Sometimes we end up doing things that aren't exactly configuration, though, or that are so nitty-gritty that making them configurable would be an awful lot of work (or not necessarily something the real maintainers want). Unfortunately, the world isn't always perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In `git` I see 2 options:

1. Have this change around, but never add it to the index. That's OK, but if your changes spans more than one file, and if you need to commit only some changes to a certain file it becomes tiresome (`git add -p`, wait, do I need that line...).
2. Always be 1 commit ahead of the remote master. Commit the changes to the master, and before committing rebase everything so that the commit you don't want to push will be on top. Then push everything to the server except of the last commit.

Let me show a quick script I've written in order to make sure your temporary commit is alway. I assume that the temporary commit will have `#alwaysontop` in the commit message.

This script basically searches for the first reachable commit with `#alwaysontop` in the commit message and rebase all changes after it so that it'll be on top. Make sure there are no conflicts with your commits and the `#alwaysontop` one, otherwise it will not work nicely.

You should make sure you never push a commit marked with `#alwaysontop` with pre-push hook.

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
        echo "Repository is dirty, only run with clean index and working tree"
        exit -1
fi

KEYWORD=':/#alwaysontop'

if ! git rev-parse $KEYWORD &>/dev/null; then
        echo No commit with $KEYWORD found
        exit -1
fi

TEMPREV=`git rev-parse $KEYWORD`
REMOTE_BRANCH=`git rev-parse $TEMPREV^`

echo @ rebasing current commit before $TEMPREV
git rebase --onto $REMOTE_BRANCH $TEMPREV && \
NEWHEAD=`git rev-parse HEAD` && \
echo @ now at $NEWHEAD moving to always-on-top commit && \
git reset --hard $TEMPREV && \
echo @ rebasing $TEMPREV to be topmost && \
git rebase $NEWHEAD
```